# What does 'dimmed the stars for a great arc' mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning

What does 'dimmed the stars **for** a great arc' mean.

> The moon was halfway up and dimmed the stars **for** a great arc.

A Wrinkle in Time by Madeleine L'Engle

Comment: @JasonBassford  it's just a typo.  I've fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

It's saying that the moon was so bright the stars appeared dimmer along a whole arc of the sky. An arc is an portion of the circumference of a circle, which would of course be just a line, so I imagine it's referring more to a sector of the sky really.

Comment: Why does 'for' apply here? With 'along' I would understand this.

Comment: "Along" would mean the same thing in this context. But it's common to say, for example, "There were trees for miles and miles" or "The sidewalk runs for 3 blocks", etc.